# How to present different column headers?

Tags: spotfire

I have a spotfire template feeded by a procedure.

And the name of the columns are something like : STATUT , COLUMN2, COLUMN3 ...

Now I need to create a "calculated column" with:
1. expression = [STATUT]
2. Column name = Statut

[image]

But when I click "Ok" (in insert Calculated Column menu), I get the following message:
"You cannot use a column name that already exists."

It seems that it's not case sensitive.

Any idea? I need to show the the calculated column header on a table, but don't want to show the names defined in the procedure.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

iindeed it is case insensitive. curious what version of Spotfire you are on, if you don't mind sharing?

anyway, to solve this, you can go to **Edit** » **Column Properties** and update the column names here.

another *possible* solution that I haven't tried is changing your expression to read `[STATUT] AS [Statut]`. this may or may not solve the issue, but either way it will be helpful to know that you can write any expression here and append `AS [My Column Name]` to change the title *for that visualization*.

Comment: Your first solution works but not for me because I need to create a "calculated column". It must be that way. The second solution I don't understand it but I will try it. Thank you for your answer niko.

Comment: @GonçaloBorges to clarify, the second solution can only be used on an axis expression or similar spot. Sorry for the confusion :)